# wix patch PYRO0103 : The system cannot find the file

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, patch, pyro

I have tried building a patch for my application. I need to replace two files, nothing more. Using a bootstrapper got the files in place, but when uninstalling the bootstrapper the files was gone and not replaced by the old ones(of course). I added Keypath=yes" to my application package(both old and new one) in hope of that would get my problem solved, but no.

I have been following this tutorial: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/patchwork

Here is my problem that I get when running this from my command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin>pyro.exe C:\Work\Dev\App\
Patch\Patch.wixmsp -out Patch.msp -t Sample C:\\Work\Dev\App\Patch\dif
f.wixmst
```

The result is this:

```
C:\Work\Dev\App\Installer_3.6.2\AppInstaller\Manager.wxs(181) :
error PYRO0103 : The system cannot find the file '..\App\3.6.2\Manager\Image
s\sort_down_small.png'.
C:\Work\Dev\App\Installer_3.6.2\AppInstaller\Manager.wxs(182) :
error PYRO0103 : The system cannot find the file '..\App\3.6.2\Manager\Image
s\sort_up_small.png'.
C:\Work\Dev\App\Installer_3.6.2\AppInstaller\Manager.wxs(182) :
error PYRO0103 : The system cannot find the file '..\App\3.6.2\Manager\Image
s\sort_up_small.png'.
............
```

The interesting thing is that my patch.wxs is not including Images.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Patch AllowRemoval="yes" Manufacturer="Company" MoreInfoURL="www.Company.com"
DisplayName="App 3.6.2 patch" Description="Small Update Patch" Classification="Update">
<Media Id='5000' Cabinet='Sample.cab'>
  <PatchBaseline Id='Sample'/>
</Media>
<PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='1.5.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
  <ComponentRef Id="Assemblies"/>
</PatchFamily>
```

What can I do?

I found this when googling: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/error-PYRO0103-The-system-cannot-find-the-file-UI-Icons-appicon-ico-if-appicon-ico-is-in-my-latest-wb-td4600799.html

And this sentence might help, but I do not understand it and googling did not give me a good examlpe:

> "Change your original command-line to light.exe by changing the
>   extension of  the .msi file to .wixout and adding these two arguments
>   to light: -xo -b"

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the arguments when creating the MSI Installers.

Say you created your installer Installer.msi like that up to now:

```
candle Installer.wxs -out Installer.wixobj
light Installer.wixobj -out Installer.msi
```

You have to change it to this

```
candle Installer.wxs -out Installer.wixobj
light -bf -xo Installer.wixobj -out Installer.wixout
light Installer.wixout -out Installer.msi
```

Do this with the old and new installer.

Now you can use torch with the .wixpdb files to create your diff.wixmst

```
torch -p -xi (PathToOldInstaller)\Installer.wixpdb (PathToNewInstaller)\Installer.wixpdb -out diff.wixmst
```

And finally create the patch

```
candle patch.wxs
light patch.wixobj
pyro patch.wixmsp -out patch.msp -t Sample diff.wixmst
```

Comment: I have not solved this yet but it also have not been working on it since march. I think you are on the right track.

Comment: Did you try the method? If yes and it is still not working, is the error still the same? This is how it solved the problem for me so i think it should work for your problem too.

Comment: As far as I remember I did get it working(ish), probably by using your method. But the installer then told me that the files did not have any differences between them. The only thing I changed was two dll-files. I replaced the old ones with two new. I have pasted the dll-file code.

"<Directory Id="AssembliesDir" Name="assemblies">
     <Component Id="Assemblies" Guid="a250abad-d933-4efa-9db3-75046cc32e36" KeyPath="yes">
      <File Id="ABootLoaderDLL" Name="BootLoader.dll" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourceDir)Manager\assemblies\BootLoader.dll" KeyPath="no" />"