# How can I use bindpaths to create a WiX Patch?

Tags: cmake, wix, cpack

I'm using cmake/cpack to build my project with WiX.

cmake runs heat.exe (or something similar) which produces files.wxs that contains the files of my project in the following format:

We'll assume a single file named a.txt inside a folder named "bin". The project is built in NewFolder on the Desktop.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="CM_DP_bin">
    <Component Id="CM_CP_bin.a.txt" Guid="*">
        <File Id="CM_FP_bin.a.txt" Source="C:/Users/mindlessbot/Desktop/NewFolder/_CPack_Packages/WIX/packageName/bin/a.txt" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

After the MSI is created, the whole NewFolder is moved in a different directory (on our server). As a result, when I try to create a WiX Patch using the output .wixpdb, I get the following error:

```
error PYRO0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:/Users/mindlessbot/Desktop/NewFolder/_CPack_Packages/WIX/packageName/bin/a.txt'
```

After some googling, I found out that the .wixpdb contains references to the files, which have changed location, so of course it can't find them. I found a thread where someone [provided the commands to use bindpaths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014795), however since I'm using cpack I can't directly call them.

So how should I got about doing this?

Some additional info:

My project contains multiple wxs files (not sure if it makes any difference)

The cpack command is:

```
path/to/cpack.exe -G WIX --config path/to/config.cmake
```

The patch command is run separately:

```
torch.exe -p -xi path/to/oldInstaller.wixpdb path/to/newInstaller.wixpdb -out path/to/patch.wixmst
candle.exe path/to/patch.wxs -out path/to/patch.wixobj
light.exe path/to/patch.wixobj -out path/to/patch/wixmsp
pyro.exe path/to/patch.wixmsp -out path/to/patch.msp -t PatchBaselineID path/to/patch/wixmst
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you would like to build your MSIs on one machine, but build the patch on another, I recommend using the `.wixout` approach rather than relying on the `.wixpdb` approach. A `.wixout` file may be generated by the same WiX Toolset CLI tool that is used to build the MSIs, `light.exe`. The `.wixout`

Full documentation on the WiX Toolset linker, `light.exe`, may be found [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html). The following is an example use of `light.exe` to build a `.wixout` file:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe" "/path/to/Some.wixobj" "/path/to/Another.wixobj" "/path/to/AndYetAnother.wixlib" -bf -xo -out "/path/to/MyInstaller_v1.wixout"`

So now let's breakdown what these command line parameters are for:

- `"/path/to/Some.wixobj" "/path/to/Another.wixobj" "/path/to/AndYetAnother.wixlib"` - These are the compiled outputs of WiX source files, they may be either `.wixobj` files (generated through `candle.exe`) or `.wixlib` files (generated through `lit.exe`, a way of consolidating `.wixobj` files into one, shareable library).
- `-bf` - This switch causes all of the files to be *bound* int the resulting `.wixout` file. This is what removes the need to have the exact folder structure on the target machine when building patches, because the files are carried with the `.wixout` file.
- `-xo` - This switch tells the linker to output an XML representation of the MSI, instead of the actual MSI. This is required to use the `-bf` switch.
- `-out "/path/to/MyInstaller_v1.wixout"` - This tells the linker where to output the `.wixout` file.

Once you have the capability of generating `.wixout` files, the `torch.exe` command can be modified to run based on `.wixout` files instead of `.wixpdb` files and their associated folder structures. The following is how I would modify your `torch.exe` command to use `.wixout` files as opposed to `.wixpdb` files:

`torch.exe -p -xi "path/to/oldInstaller.wixout" "path/to/newInstaller.wixout" -out "path/to/patch.wixmst"`

So, all in all I really like this approach, and generally I make my build process produce both an `.msi` and a `.wixout` file. This allows us to cache various builds/versions of our installer as `.wixout` files, and then the process of creating a patch between various versions of the `.wixout` files becomes relatively easy.